# Test class not covering code in batch apex

Tags: unit-test, batch, failing-tests

HI I created a batch apex but my test class is not covering the entire code, not sure where i am going wrong. Looks like query in start method is not returning any test records which i created. Please shed some light on where i am going wrong.

```
global class updatePrimaryZipTerritory implements Database.Batchable<sobject>{
    public String query='select id,Zip_vod__c,INDV_CL_Territory__c,Country_vod__c from Address_vod__c where Primary_vod__c=TRUE AND Country_vod__c=\'us\'';
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        List<Address_vod__c> ad=[select id,Zip_vod__c,INDV_CL_Territory__c,Country_vod__c from Address_vod__c where Primary_vod__c=TRUE AND Country_vod__c='us'];
        System.debug('****'+ad.size());
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sobject> scope){
        List<Address_vod__c> addrList=(List<Address_vod__c>)scope;
        System.debug('Query List'+addrList);
        List<Address_vod__c> updateTerr=new List<Address_vod__c>();
        Set<String> zipIds=new Set<String>();
        for(Address_vod__c ad:addrList){
            if(ad.Zip_vod__c!='')
            zipIds.add(ad.Zip_vod__c);
        }
        System.debug('Zip Codes'+zipIds+'Size'+zipIds.size());
         Map<String,String> zipTerr=new Map<String,String>();
        for(INDV_Zip_To_Territory__c zip:[select Name,INDV_Territory_Id__c from INDV_Zip_To_Territory__c where Name in: zipIds]){
                        zipTerr.put(zip.Name,zip.INDV_Territory_Id__c);
        }
        System.debug('Map of Zip Terr'+zipTerr+'Size'+zipTerr.size());
        if(!zipTerr.isEmpty()){
        for(Address_vod__c add:addrList){
            if(zipTerr.containsKey(add.Zip_vod__c)){
                if(String.isBlank(add.INDV_CL_Territory__c) || zipTerr.get(add.Zip_vod__c)!=add.INDV_CL_Territory__c){
                    add.INDV_CL_Territory__c=zipTerr.get(add.Zip_vod__c);
                    updateTerr.add(add);
                }
            }                
        }
        }    
        System.debug('Update Territory List'+updateTerr+updateTerr.size());
        if(!updateTerr.isEmpty()){
            update updateTerr;
        }
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

       }
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
private class updatePrimaryZipTerritoryTest {
   static testmethod void updateTerritoryTestMethod(){
        List<INDV_Zip_To_Territory__c> zip_terr=new List<INDV_Zip_To_Territory__c>();
        List<Address_vod__c> addrList=new List<Address_vod__c>();
         Account acc=new Account(lastName='Test Batch');
        insert acc;
       List<String> zip=new List<String>{'00680', '00681', '00682', '00683', '00684', '00685', '00686', '00687', '00688', '00689'};
        for(integer i=0;i<10;i++){
            addrList.add(new Address_vod__c(Account_vod__c=acc.id,Name='test'+i,Primary_vod__c=TRUE,Country_vod__c='us',city_vod__c='test',State_vod__c='VA',Zip_vod__c=zip[i]));
      zip_terr.add(new INDV_Zip_To_Territory__c(Name=zip[i],INDV_Territory_Id__c='29999999'));
        }
        insert addrList;
       insert zip_terr;

        system.debug('Before Address+++'+addrList);

        Test.startTest();
        updatePrimaryZipTerritory cb=new updatePrimaryZipTerritory();
         //cb.query='select id,Zip_vod__c,INDV_CL_Territory__c,Country_vod__c from Address_vod__c where Primary_vod__c=TRUE AND Country_vod__c=\'us\'';
        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(cb);
        Test.stopTest();

        system.debug('After Address+++'+addrList);
      System.assertEquals(7,[select count() from Address_vod__c where INDV_CL_Territory__c!='']);
    }
}
```

Comment: What bits are not covered ?

Comment: Which lines are not getting converted as far as I understand if your test class was successful it should have covered the batch class.\

Comment: why are you querying again when you have a query string in the start method, not sure this will fix but try changing the start method like below,                           public String query=
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        string query= 'select id,Zip_vod__c,INDV_CL_Territory__c,Country_vod__c from Address_vod__c where Primary_vod__c=TRUE AND Country_vod__c=\'us\'';
        System.debug('****'+ad.size());
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

Comment: @Shankish Execute method is not covering. I think my start method is not returning any of my test records. Is there a way to check how many records returned from start method?

Comment: Yes, turn on your logs. You have already printed your SOQL. ELse write this line System.debug(Database.getQueryLocator(query));

Comment: %%Database.QueryLocator[Query=select id,Zip_vod__c,INDV_CL_Territory__c,Country_vod__c from Address_vod__c where Primary_vod__c=TRUE AND Country_vod__c='us']ggregations:0|select id,Zip_vod__c,INDV_CL_Territory__c,Country_vod__c from Address_vod__c where Primary_vod__c=TRUE AND Country_vod__c='us'
10:14:47.352 (3530433184)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[11]|Rows:0 this is what i am getting, looks like it is not returning any records, please help me how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below test class, i have changed the data creation to setup method to see if it works.

```
@isTest
private class updatePrimaryZipTerritoryTest {

    @testSetup static void testData(){

    List<INDV_Zip_To_Territory__c> zip_terr=new List<INDV_Zip_To_Territory__c>();
            List<Address_vod__c> addrList=new List<Address_vod__c>();
             Account acc=new Account(lastName='Test Batch');
            insert acc;
           List<String> zip=new List<String>{'00680', '00681', '00682', '00683', '00684', '00685', '00686', '00687', '00688', '00689'};
            for(integer i=0;i<10;i++){
                addrList.add(new Address_vod__c(Account_vod__c=acc.id,Name='test'+i,Primary_vod__c=TRUE,Country_vod__c='us',city_vod__c='test',State_vod__c='VA',Zip_vod__c=zip[i]));
          zip_terr.add(new INDV_Zip_To_Territory__c(Name=zip[i],INDV_Territory_Id__c='29999999'));
            }
            insert addrList;
           insert zip_terr;

            system.debug('Before Address+++'+addrList);

    }

       static testmethod void updateTerritoryTestMethod(){


        Test.startTest();
        updatePrimaryZipTerritory cb=new updatePrimaryZipTerritory();
         //cb.query='select id,Zip_vod__c,INDV_CL_Territory__c,Country_vod__c from Address_vod__c where Primary_vod__c=TRUE AND Country_vod__c=\'us\'';
        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(cb);
        Test.stopTest();

        system.debug('After Address+++'+addrList);
      System.assertEquals(7,[select count() from Address_vod__c where INDV_CL_Territory__c!='']);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using another query to check how many records it is actually returning in debug logs, it shows 0 records for that query in logs. I feel that start method is not returning any records which i created in test class. Is there any other way to check this? My execute method is not at all covering, please help me

Comment: so you are saying both the queries are returning null after querying?

Comment: List<Address_vod__c> ad=[select id,Zip_vod__c,INDV_CL_Territory__c,Country_vod__c from Address_vod__c where Primary_vod__c=TRUE AND Country_vod__c='us'];
        System.debug('****'+ad.size()); this is showing 0 in debug logs, so i think query locator also doing the same. Any suggestions

Comment: please check the database.getquerylocator in debug logs and make sure on what it returns.

Comment: Yes it is returning 0 records, i dont know where i am doing wrong, can you please help me.

Comment: @sam i have updated the answer, please try the test class i posted

Comment: i tried with your code but still no luck, Database.query(query) returns 0 records in start method

Comment: can you debug in the test class after insertion, to see how the records are created?

Comment: try setting a batch size in test class as follwoing, Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(cb,200);

Comment: Address_vod__c:{Account_vod__c=0011700000UuL0hAAF, Name=test0, Primary_vod__c=true, Country_vod__c=us, City_vod__c=test, State_vod__c=VA, Zip_vod__c=00680, Id=a01170000067mcRAAQ}, Address_vod__c:{Account_vod__c=0011700000UuL0hAAF, Name=test1, Primary_vod__c=true, Country_vod__c=us, City_vod__c=test, State_vod__c=VA, Zip_vod__c=00681, Id=a01170000067mcSAAQ} yes created records are displaying in logs

Comment: can you set batch size as my above comment and see

Comment: Yes i tried it but no luck.

Comment: Hmmmm, can you try changing the start method definiation like below and see,       global Iterable<sobject> start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

Comment: i made some changes to my test code by creating test records and now it works fine. Thanks for taking your time and responding to my questions.